# Unable to connect AWS quicksight to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-quicksight

When I try to connect\create Data source to S3 from Quicksight, I get the error:

```
Cannot Create Datasource
```

I am providing the URL of the S3 bucket. I also changed to access permission of the S3 bucket to public and added the same in Quicksight.

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error message]

Answer (score 5):

You have to provide a [manifest file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-manifest-file-format.html), and not the link to your datasource. It is counterintuitive, but make things easier when you have to upload a large number of files (or all the files in one or more directories).

In your example, a manifest file could look like:

```
{
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "https://s3.amazonaws.com/deeeeep/test"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Save it locally (eg: deep-test-manifest.json), then and *upload* it. Optionally, upload it to your s3 bucket and reference its URL, and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Andre mentioned above, I'm sharing the Manifest template that worked with me:

```
    {
    "fileLocations": [
        {
            "URIs": [
                "s3://yourS3bucketName/YourFileName.csv"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "globalUploadSettings": {
        "format": "CSV",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "containsHeader": "true"
    }
}
```